# Agregar nuevos input con clase autoNumeric

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, autonumeric

tengo mi código:

```
var tr = '<tr class="tr_new">';
      tr +='<td><input type="text" name="txt_comi_cond1[]" class="moneda" size="10"></td>';
      tr +='<td><input type="text" name="txt_comi_cond2[]" class="moneda" size="10"></td>';
      tr +='<td><input type="text" name="txt_comi_porcen[]" class="porcentaje" size="10"></td>';
      tr +='<td><a href="#add" class="btn_del">-</a></td>';
    tr +='</tr>';
```

al agregar con append(), no funciona la clase moneda, que este código:

```
$('.moneda').autoNumeric({aSep: ',',aDec: '.',vMin: '0',vMax: '9999999.99'});
```

Pero si lo ejecuto esto $('.moneda').autoNumeric() después de hacer el append(), los input anteriores se alteran, si ingreso un número lo duplica, alguna idea de como agregar nuevos input y que apliquen esta clase?

Comment: Necesariamente necesitas aplicar autoNumeric luego de agregar la nueva fila. Intenta llamar a `.autoNumeric('destroy')` antes de volver a inicializarlos: `$('.moneda').autoNumeric('destroy'); $('.moneda').autoNumeric('init', { tus opciones })`.

Comment: Justamente eso e intentado, agregar la fila nueva a la tabla, luego ejecutar .autoNumeric('destroy') y luego .autoNumeric('init',{}), pero no funciona aun me sigue alterando a los input anteriores.

Comment: En ese caso te sugiero que pruebes la respuesta de @amenadiel. Luego que agregues la fila, **buscas los elementos** `.moneda` **sobre la fila recientemente agregada** y aplicas `autoNumeric` a ellas; dejando las anteriores intactas.

Comment: Así es amigo, me funcionó la de @amenadiel, ya le agradecí e igualmente muchas gracias a ti.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin conocer autoNumeric, para cualquier plugin que opere sobre un input y no sea idempotente, al añadir un nuevo elemento debieras guardar una referencia a éste y aplicar el plugin sólo sobre él, y no sobre todo el conjunto de "hermanos" que ya están en el DOM.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso de uso, podrías hacer:

```
var tr = $('<tr class="tr_new"></tr>');
  tr.append('<td><input type="text" name="txt_comi_cond1[]" class="moneda" size="10"></td>');
  tr.append('<td><input type="text" name="txt_comi_cond2[]" class="moneda" size="10"></td>');
  tr.append('<td><input type="text" name="txt_comi_porcen[]" class="porcentaje" size="10"></td>');
  tr.append('<td><a href="#add" class="btn_del">-</a></td>');
```

Y luego añadir a la tabla que debes tener en tu DOM

```
  tabla.append(tr);
  tr.find('.moneda').autoNumeric({...});
```

De manera de alimentar a autoNumeric únicamente con la fila que acabas de añadir y no con toda la tabla.

Considerando el comentario de @GustavoGarcia y dado que autoNumeric tiene un método destroy, su solución es más precisa para tu caso de uso.

Comment: Usé 'destroy' pero no me funcionó, he usado tu forma y sí me ha funcionado, gracias por compartir conocimiento, muchas gracias.